# divs within divs jump to next line in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html

I know this problem is probably discussed everyday here already, but I am still having problems with the display of my divisions in IE9. Most solutions point to overflow:hidden and whitespace:nowrap, or adding extra margin-right, but none of these seem to work.

here is my css part:

```
form.cmxform fieldset{
margin: 1em 2.4em 2.4em;
padding: 1em 2em 1em 2em;
border:2px solid black;
background:#FCFCFC;
}

form.cmxform legend {
font-size:14pt;
padding: 2 5 5 5px;
font-weight: bold;

}
form.cmxform label {

vertical-align: top;
text-align:left;
float: left;
width:450px;
}
form.cmxform fieldset ol {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
form.cmxform fieldset li {
list-style: none;
padding: 5px;
margin: 0;
}  

div {
         display: inline-block;
         overflow: hidden;
         white-space: nowrap;
         }

li > div{
/*  width:750px;*/
border:none;
font-size:14px;
border:1px solid red; /* added for visibility */
display: inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
margin-right:3px;
}

li > div > div {
display: inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
border:1px solid black; /* added for visibility */
text-align:center;      /* added for style */
width:100px;
float:left;
margin-right:3px;
}
```

and here's the html it should apply to.

```
<form action="verwerking.php" method="post" class="cmxform">
<fieldset>
<legend>Hoe is dit kind op de peuterspeelzaal?</legend>
  <ol>
     <li><label>&nbsp;</label><div><div>Zeker Niet</div><div>&nbsp;</div><div>&nbsp;   </div><div>&nbsp;</div><div>Zeker Wel</div></div></li>
     <li><label>&nbsp;</label><div><div>--</div><div>-</div><div>0</div><div>+</div><div>++</div></div></li>
     <li><label>Dit kind neemt zonder problemen afscheid van de ouder</label><div>
     <div><input type="radio" name="p_afsche_pr13" value="1"></div>
     <div><input type="radio" name="p_afsche_pr13" value="2"></div>
     <div><input type="radio" name="p_afsche_pr13" value="3"></div>
     <div><input type="radio" name="p_afsche_pr13" value="4"></div>
     <div><input type="radio" name="p_afsche_pr13" value="5"></div></div></li>
</ol>
</fieldset>
```

Its running correctly in chrome at the moment, but IE doesn't seems to agree with it. Anybody have any ideas please?
thanks!

Comment: I don't get this issue. Just tested on IE9 your demo. http://jsfiddle.net/XuD6j/

Comment: Hmm, Ive opened your fiddle in IE9, and it seems to work indeed, but then I wonder why it's not working on my actual web page: http://www.doenwatikkan.nl/jeroen/login.php
It's the second page after the welcome page. I didn't want to post the whole thing, as it's a bit messy, but there must be something extra that's incompatible with IE9 then.

Comment: I'm sure there should be a css property somewhere that sets the `div`s to `display:block`. Let me check.

Comment: @Jeroen, is there something not good with the answer?

Comment: @ caramba: The problem turned out to be in the header information rather than in the css. IE was running in quirky mode. Once this was fixed the css displayed correctly unchanged

Answer (score 0):

add width:600px; to form.cmxform fieldset {}

```
form.cmxform fieldset {
    margin: 1em 2.4em 2.4em;
    padding: 1em 2em 1em 2em;
    border:2px solid black;
    background:#FCFCFC;
    width:600px;
}
```

your html would be much easyer to read if you post it like this:
(no changes have been made here, just whitespace in the code)

```
<form action="verwerking.php" method="post" class="cmxform">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Hoe is dit kind op de peuterspeelzaal?</legend>
    <ol>
        <li>
            <label>&nbsp;</label>
            <div>
                <div>Zeker Niet</div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <div>Zeker Wel</div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>&nbsp;</label>
            <div>
                <div>--</div>
                <div>-</div>
                <div>0</div>
                <div>+</div>
                <div>++</div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>Dit kind neemt zonder problemen afscheid van de ouder</label>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <input type="radio" name="p_afsche_pr13" value="1">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="radio" name="p_afsche_pr13" value="2">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="radio" name="p_afsche_pr13" value="3">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="radio" name="p_afsche_pr13" value="4">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="radio" name="p_afsche_pr13" value="5">
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ol>
</fieldset>
```

also google quickly for "html span". A span tag is an inline element. you can use a span with style="display:block;" or "display:inline-block;" in this case you could change all divs inside the li with a

```
<span style="display:inline-block;">xxxXXXxxx</span>
```

and you dont need to float anything